# useEffects keeps looping for infinity

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback, react-usecallback

Pardon me if this is a silly question. Im a new react learner. Im trying using a create react app. I am using a custom hook for API handling only. Now I want the useEffect to run only when the data changes. Thats why I put it in dependency. But yet it keeps rendering for infinity. What is the problem? Or how should I handle this?
Thank you.

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const useAPI = (url, options) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const getDogCollection = useCallback(() => {
        fetch(url, options)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(data, "----DI---", result);
                setData(result);
            });
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        getDogCollection();
    }, [data]);

    return data;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you've given data as one of the dependencies, but the function called in your useEffect updates data, so it then runs again.

You can change it to the length, like this, and it should work:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getDogCollection();
}, [data.length]);
```

Comment: This will cause at least one extra fetch of dogs. I don't think that's what OP wants.

Comment: Thanks a ton. So far this seems like the solution I was looking for. I know I could just add an empty dependency array to avoid the issue. But I was looking for the answer that why even if it is the same data yet keeps looking. I have my answer now. Its because the data as object although the value is same yet every time returns a new object. and length or any primitive data type can solve the issue.

Comment: @CnerdMahadi Just so you know, this will _not_ do the right thing if the dogs change but there's the same amount of them...

Comment: @AKX, Could you explain brother? I quite didnt get what you said.

Answer (score 1):

You'll just want `url` and `options` to be the dependencies, not `data` (because you *set* it in the effect!).

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const useAPI = (url, options) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url, options)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(setData);
    // TODO: add error handling...
  }, [url, options]);
  return data;
};
```

However, you'll probably just want to look at [swr](https://swr.vercel.app/) instead of writing this hook yourself.

Comment: I actually already did that. And I know it could solve the issue. I was more of looking for the answer of why the data being the same yet keeps looping. I have the answer now. Thanks a lot for the help man <3